# Displaying R ggplots inline in jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, r, ggplot2, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run a simple example found here: https://www.datacamp.com/community/blog/jupyter-notebook-r#gs.OczVCjA

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
# Load in the r magic

import rpy2.ipython

%reload_ext rpy2.ipython

# We need ggplot2

%R require(ggplot2)
%R library("ggplot2")
# Load in the pandas library
import pandas as pd 
# Make a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'Alphabet': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'],
                   'A': [4, 3, 5, 2, 1, 7, 7, 5, 9],
                   'B': [0, 4, 3, 6, 7, 10,11, 9, 13],
                   'C': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]})
# Take the name of input variable df and assign it to an R variable of the same name
%R -i df
# Plot the DataFrame df
ggplot(data=df) + geom_point(aes(x=A, y=B, color=C))
```

At first I had a NameError "ggplot node defined"

I then added %R to the last line and now obtain the following output:

```
R object with classes: ('gg', 'ggplot') mapped to:
<ListVector - Python:0x7fc6a73c1d88 / R:0x3c4e768>
[DataF..., ListV..., Envir..., ..., Envir..., Envir..., ListV...]
R object with classes: ('gg', 'ggplot') mapped to:
<ListVector - Python:0x7fc6a73c1d88 / R:0x3c4e768>
[DataF..., ListV..., Envir..., ..., Envir..., Envir..., ListV...]
R object with classes: ('gg', 'ggplot') mapped to:
<ListVector - Python:0x7fc6a73c1d88 / R:0x3c4e768>
[DataF..., ListV..., Envir..., ..., Envir..., Envir..., ListV...]
  scales: <class 'rpy2.robjects.environments.Environment'>
  R object with classes: ('ScalesList', 'ggproto') mapped to:
<Environment - Python:0x7fc6a7682808 / R:0x215a968>
  ...
  data: <class 'rpy2.robjects.environments.Environment'>
  R object with classes: ('FacetNull', 'Facet', 'ggproto') mapped to:
<Environment - Python:0x7fc6a76829c8 / R:0x281c138>
  layers: <class 'rpy2.robjects.environments.Environment'>
  R object with classes: ('environment',) mapped to:
<Environment - Python:0x7fc6a7682548 / R:0x1544d58>
R object with classes: ('gg', 'ggplot') mapped to:
<ListVector - Python:0x7fc6a73c1d88 / R:0x3c4e768>
[DataF..., ListV..., Envir..., ..., Envir..., Envir..., ListV...]
```

Was a plot created and how to display it inline in the notebook like one would do with matplotlib?

n.b.: I installed R within Jupyter using the command conda install -c r r-essentials (which normally includes ggplot?) as described in the link above

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, i tried it now... 
This worked for me:

`%R print(ggplot(data=df) + geom_point(aes(x=A, y=B, color=C)))`

You have to add a `print()` statement. Don't know why.

Comment: Thanks, it works. i wonder why it's required here, would be good to find out.