# ggplot graphs not outputting Jupytr Notebook (R/tidyverse)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, jupyter-notebook

My jupytr notebook won't output any of my gig-lot objects no matter what I do. I've restarted the kernel, jupytr notebook, Anaconda Navigator, and my computer and nothing seems to help. I've tried opening new notebooks and reformatting but nothing is working. 
 [image: Things I've Tried]

Comment: Have a look at the problem here and see if this solution helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43975244/displaying-r-ggplots-inline-in-jupyter-notebooks

Comment: I also tried using print and that did not work.